# how to create MDI form in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I solve this problem "Cannot Create Forms. No MDI forms are currently active". I want to make a simple program that wod require a Login Form before it can acess the main form. I got three forms: Main Form (MDI Form), Form2 (MDIChild) and Login Form (Normal). Login form would appear first then the Main Form, then when I try to call on Form 2 from the Main form, an error would display "Cannot Create Forms. No MDI forms are currently active". 
I am using Delphi 7 on windows XP. I'm a beginner. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Yes, what Ken said! Make sure that the only form which you create with Application.CreateForm is your main form. If you do that, you'll be fine.

Comment: MDI applications in a multi-monitor world don't really work.  Just spawn new processes, or re-implement the good bits from MDI in your SDI application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're letting your LoginForm be auto-created, and it's being created first. This won't work, because the first form created by `Application.CreateForm` in the project file becomes the `Application.MainForm`. In order by be an MDI application, the `MainForm` must be a MDI parent window.

The solution is usually to not auto-create your login form, and instead create it yourself. To do so, you need to edit your .dpr file (`Project->View Source` from the IDE's main menu).

Your project source should look something like this now (obviously, using your classes in the `Application.CreateForm` calls):

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TLoginForm, LoginForm);
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.CreateForm(TChildForm, ChildForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

You need to modify it so that the `LoginForm` isn't created first.

```
var
  LoginOK: Boolean = False;

begin
  LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create(nil);
  try
    // Show login form. When it closes, see if login worked.
    LoginForm.ShowModal;
    LoginOK := LoginForm.CanLogin; // However you know login is OK or not here
  finally
    LoginForm.Free;
  end;
  if not LoginOK then
    Halt;    // Login failed - terminate application.
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  {
     I normally do not auto-create anything but the main form
     and maybe a datamodule (which you **can** autocreate first -
     it is not a form), but a MDI application is pretty useless
     without at least one open child window, IMO.
  }
  Application.CreateForm(TChildForm, ChildForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: @David:Thanks. Of course you're right - my mistake. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Cool, +1. Another example of login form is in (http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/password_login.htm)